# Add items to a custom ExtJs component in Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, custom-component, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

I have created a custom component in ExtJs via Sencha Architect. I would like to add items to this component at the instance-level, not at the class-level, but the drag/drop interface won't allow my instances to receive items. I can drop items on the class definition, but not on the instances.

I am guessing I need to add some sort of config to the class definition, but so far I've had no success.

Thanks in advance.